# Python - convert JSON to image(.jpg)

Tags: json, image-processing, faster-rcnn

I filtered Microsoft COCO dataset by filter.py from [here](https://github.com/immersive-limit/coco-manager), which generate a filtered.JSON file, and I'm wondering is there a way to convert JSON to images(.jpg) ?

Actually I'm doing a Mask R-CNN project to perform instance segmentation, and don't really how to deal with the training data I filtered.

Answer (score 0):

pip install fiftyone, and use this tool's App might be helpful.
[reference](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-work-with-object-detection-datasets-in-coco-format-9bf4fb5848a4)

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Aspose.Total for Python](https://products.aspose.com/total/python-java/conversion/json-to-images/) for JSON to Image (JPEG, PNG, BMP, TIFF) conversion via Python.

```
import  jpype     
import  asposecells     
jpype.startJVM() 
from asposecells.api import Workbook
workbook = Workbook("input.json")
workbook.save("Output.jpg")
jpype.shutdownJVM()
```